What is the Christmas-like song featured in the demo of 'The Polynomial'?
I played the demo version of The Polynomial last year on Steam. There was a song on the demo track that had a Christmas-like feel to it. It sounded similar to Jingle Bells, perhaps a cover version of it.
If anyone could point me to the track name, perhaps a mp3 or YouTube link, or even just the author, that would be awesome!

[Undeleted] [Reopened] - Game music identification has been on-topic for a while now.

Here you go:



I'd say it's sort of an electronic version of Jingle Bells.  I found it via the developer's blog.
